# The website encountered an unexpected error. try again later

Tags: 7, debugging

Hi guys I get this message when trying to get acces to my web loging as admin this is the error 
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
is only when trying to get access to manage the content posted for other users overlay=admin/content
this is the information I have from recent los messages

Location    admin/content?render=overlay

> Message   PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:
>   1146 Table 'gamesswa_gamenetcouk.field_data_field_link_text' doesn't
>   exist: SELECT t.* FROM {field_data_field_link_text} t WHERE
>   (entity_type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (entity_id IN
>   (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) AND (language IN
>   (:db_condition_placeholder_2)) AND (deleted =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_3) ORDER BY delta ASC; Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => node [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =>
>   31 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => und [:db_condition_placeholder_3]
>   => 0 ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_load() (line 412 of /home/gamesswa/public_html/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).

I have been for days trying to fix this but i cant, could anyone please help me with this, thanks

Comment: Check your database tables; Drupal can't select from the `field_data_field_link_text` table; It might not exist in the DB, you could be connected to the wrong DB, or the connected account can't access it.

Comment: The script can't connect with the db. Might be a problem with config, with the servers, with db... php log says what? Can you log into the db?

Comment: Hi I can see that on my DB the table field_data_field_link_text does not exist, what can i do?, how to fix this?, thanks

Comment: Do you have a backup of db ?